# Date timezone is lost between my AngularJS controller and Backend entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive, entity-framework-6

I'm facing an issue with date timezoning missed between AngularJS and Entity Framework.

This is a sample of my angular code: [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/iRf9JbnimP4fsC3sIcSD?p=preview)

I get date from server side (ASP.NET MVC5) as string like this: `"2015-02-17T00:00:00"` without any info about timezone.

To parse this string as date and bind it to input[date], I'm using angularjs directive for this.

**My problem is**: my local timezone is +4, after changing the value and pushing it back to the ngModel, it is converted to UTC time, so date part will be -1 day back. In other words, if I select `Feb 18, 2015` in the date input, the ngModel value will be: `2015-02-17T20:00:00.000Z`. So, when passed back to the server, I receive it in the controller like this:

```
{5/17/1988 8:00:00 PM}
    Date: {5/17/1988 12:00:00 AM}
    dateData: 5238841010427387904
    Day: 17
    DayOfWeek: Tuesday
    DayOfYear: 138
    Hour: 20
    InternalKind: 4611686018427387904
    InternalTicks: 627154992000000000
    Kind: Utc
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 5
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 627154992000000000
    TimeOfDay: {20:00:00}
    Year: 1988
```

The kind of this date is `Utc`. But when I pass it to the DB throught Entity framework (v6) it is saved without any timezoning. So, next time I'm loading it, it will be in local timezone, so with -4 hours from the original value, which is wrong.

This date attribute in entity framework model is simple, just like this `public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }` and in DB (MSSQL) it is of type DateTime like this: `[BirthDate] DATETIME NOT NULL`

I think the solution should be: either to force Angular to use only local timezone, while my application will run only locally, or to force entity framework to save timezone info.

I prefer to go with first option, but **how**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the return type of angularJS directive from Date object to string with `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Before:

```
(function() {
  function parseDateString(dateString) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof dateString || '' === dateString) {
      return null;
    }
    var parts = dateString.split('-');
    var year = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    var month = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
    var day = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
    return new Date(year, (month - 1), day);
  }

  var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', [])
    .directive('input', ['dateFilter',
      function(dateFilter) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          require: '?ngModel',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if ('undefined' !== typeof attrs.type && 'date' === attrs.type && ngModel) {
              ngModel.$formatters = [ function(modelValue) { return dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); } ];
              ngModel.$parsers = [ function(viewValue) { return parseDateString(viewValue); } ];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]).controller("myController", function($scope) {
      $scope.testDate = "2015-02-17T00:00:00";
    });
}());
```

After:

```
(function() {  
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', [])
  .directive('input', ['dateFilter',
    function(dateFilter) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          if ('undefined' !== typeof attrs.type && 'date' === attrs.type && ngModel) {
            ngModel.$formatters = [
              function(modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
              }
            ];
            ngModel.$parsers = [
              function(viewValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
              }
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]).controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.testDate = "2015-02-17T00:00:00";
  });
}());
```